# How to run arbitrary query with prisma?

Tags: node.js, prisma

In my case complete query string is initially unknown, there is a number of conditions

let conditions: string[] = ['wm_id = "40"'];

So I have the query (first attempt)

```
    let sql = Prisma.sql`
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs
      WHERE ${conditions.join(' OR ')}
    `;
    console.log(`
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs
      WHERE ${conditions.join(' OR ')}
    `)
    console.log(sql);
    let ret = await prisma.$queryRaw(sql);
    console.log('return=', ret);
```

and it prints

```
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs
      WHERE wm_id = "40"

U {
  values: [ 'wm_id = "40"' ],
  strings: [
    '\n      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs\n      WHERE ',
    '\n    '
  ]
}
return= [ { 'COUNT(*)': 0n } ]
```

printed query string runs successfully in Adminer and returns 9000, not zero.

next attempt

```
    let str = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs
      WHERE ${conditions.join(' OR ')}`;  
    let sql = Prisma.sql`${str}`;
    console.log(sql);

    let ret = await prisma.$queryRaw(sql);
```

prints

```
U {
  values: [ 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs\n      WHERE wm_id = "40"' ],
  strings: [ '', '' ]
}
[Nest] 19358  - 09/01/2023, 3:21:28 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler]
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:
```

and finnaly

```
    let str = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postback_logs
      WHERE ${conditions.join(' OR ')}`;  
    let ret = await prisma.$queryRaw(str);
```

prints

```
PrismaClientValidationError: `$queryRaw` is a tag function, please use it like the following:
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ${1} OR email = ${'user@email.com'};`
```

"@prisma/client": "^5.1.1",

it it possible at all?